# "Microsoft Excel has stopped working” error closing an xlsb file

Tags: vba, excel

Running Excel 2010 on Win 7 64 bit.

I encountered this problem while working on a quite large application, and is a difficult one to explain via text, but I’ll do my best. My initial  thought was that I had a corrupted workbook, however after a day or two I found that wasn’t the case, and eventually managed to drill down to a scenario that I could replicate.

To demonstrate this problem:

1 - create a new workbook (Book1)

2 - Add the code to  a regular module

3 - Add the  2 named formulas.

4 - Add a form button to sheet1, and assign it to macro `CloseMe`

5 - Save as `Book1.xlsb`.

```
Sub CloseMe()
   ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

`aaaa = Sheet1!$A$1`

`bbbb = OFFSET(Sheet1!aaaa,0,0,5,1)`

This demo requires 2 workbooks to be open at the same time, so open a 2nd workbook.  Activate Book1.

1. click the button, Book1 should close.
2. Re-open Book1
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2

If you can do step 3 ten  times or more without an error, then edit name “aaaa” and change the name to something else (“mmmm”), and Save

Now, after about 3 iterations of step 3, Excel crashes, and I get the message “Microsoft Excel has stopped working”, etc

Oddly, the problem goes away if I change formula `bbbb` to a cell reference, eg,  `bbbb = OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,5,1)`.  Also, there’s no problem with `xls` or `xlsm` versions of the same file.

What I’ve tried:

1. Repairing MS Office 2010.
2. Uninstalling MS Office, with Revo, and re-installing.
3. Had a friend try it on his computer, with the same results.
4. No luck with this searching on the Internet.

So at this point it looks  to be an issue with Excel 2010 xlsb.  I’ve been struggling with this for over a week, but have not come up with a solution/work around.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

A few days later: corrected a couple of typos, also discovered that after about 3 cycles of Open/Close, the formula `bbbb` value is now either blank, or else contains garbage data.  And the subsequent Close will cause Excel to crash.

Comment: I have read that xlsb files while performing some operations faster than xls and xlsm (all can handle macros), are much more prone to workbook corruption, therefore I will never risk this performance increase. It may not be closely connected to this case, but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk  I appreciate your reply, and note your concern.  However, in this case the scenario setup is so simple that workbook corruption is unlikely to be an issue.